# What is the difference between using AddDbContextCheck and AddSqlServer for HealthCheck?

Tags: c#, health-check

I have this code which can be used to check the database health using C# in NET 6.

Version 1:

```
var hcBuilder = builder.Services.AddHealthChecks();    
hcBuilder.AddSqlServer(myServicesConnStr);
```

Version 2:

```
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddDbContextCheck<MyServicesContext>();
```

What is the difference between version 1 and version 2 in regards to checking the health of the database using HealthCheck package? Is there any difference in its efficiency?

Answer (score 4):

Version 1. from **AspNetCore.HealthChecks.SqlServer**
: It is not maintained or supported by Microsoft.

Version 2.  from **Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore**
: It is maintained and supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

`AddSqlServer` uses a `SqlConnection` directly under the hood.

`AddDbContextCheck` will use a `DbContext` with its configuration to do a query. It will use the configured execution strategy for the `DbContext` as well, so if you are registering it with [`EnableRetryOnFailure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-resiliency) then the health check query will also be retried in case of a connection failure.